# Как скомпилировать такой код на C#?

Tags: c#

Изучая исходники .NET наткнулся на такой код:

```
        var a = new char[3] { 'a', 'B', 'c' };
        AssertExtensions.AssertThrows<InvalidOperationException, char>(a, a => 
        {
            ReadOnlySpan<char> source = a;
            Span<char> destination = a;
            source.ToLower(destination, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        });
```

Компилятор выдаёт ошибку:

```
Error   CS0136  A local or parameter named 'a' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter
```

Интересно, как это можно скомпилировать? У них же, наверняка, этот код как-то работает?

Comment: Так это тесты-же вроде? А это строка `AssertExtensions.AssertThrows<InvalidOperationException, char>` ожидает как раз таки `InvalidOperationException`. Клонируйте `https://github.com/dotnet/corefx.git` либо загрузите как ZIP-архив и компилируйте.

Comment: @Vasek что именно? Укажите строку или напишите более развёрнуто пожалуйста.

Comment: @Vasek скорее всего я не понимаю, что Вы имеете ввиду. Чем тип `InvalidOperationException` не подходит под ограничение `where E : Exception`? Или вы что-то другое хотите сказать?

Comment: @XelaNimed я просто не могу понять, что вы пытались сказать в первом коментарии. Это вроде не совсем имеет отношение к ответу.

Comment: @Vasek на мой взгляд это имеет отношение к приведённому участку кода и ошибке компилятора.

Comment: @XelaNimed как?